# My Constructor won't construct or "return" what should be returned

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

This is my Constructor:

```
public class OrderedIntList extends ArrayList{


    public OrderedIntList(int ... elements) {
        ArrayList <Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        for(int i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            temp.add(elements[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1,2,4,5,3};
    OrderedIntList la = new OrderedIntList(a);
    System.out.println(la);
}
```

When I run it the output is: `[ ]`. So technically the constructor dint give back the construct right? how do i fix this?

Comment: Please format your code and don't post in caps.

Comment: Why would it return anything but `[]`. All you are doing is adding the elements to a local ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor you initialized local `ArrayList` which holds elements passed in constructor, but `toString` is not aware of this local list and is printing elements held by inherited structure from class you extend - ArrayList. So consider changing your constructor to

```
public OrderedIntList(int... elements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        this.add(elements[i]);// your class extends ArrayList 
                              // so it inherited structure to store elements
                              // and toString is base on this structure
                              // not on local list declared in constructor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet for adding occures that much, a utility functions exists in class Collections.
I have made an alternative with addAll.

```
public class OrderedIntList extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    public OrderedIntList(int... elements) {
        for (int element : elements) {
            add(element);
        }
    }

    public OrderedIntList(Integer... elements) {
        Collections.addAll(this, elements);
    }

}
```

Also ArrayList is parametrised.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much and for the utility function! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding element to `temp` list in your constructor, instead you should add to your list like this

```
        for(int i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            add(elements[i]);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a local ArrayList in the constructor:

```
OrderedIntList(int... elements) {
    ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
```

You should write the passed values directly:

```
public OrderedIntList(int... elements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        add(elements[i]);
    }
}
```